# Some user interaction problems when showing/hiding an Emberjs TextField according to a property in my model

Tags: ember.js

Sorry about the long and convoluted title, but I couldn't summarize it better.

I have a simple model, with a property `foo`, initialized to `null`.

In my view, I don't want to display an input field when `foo` is `null` or `""`, and have a button that says *Add foo*.

```
<a href="#" class="btn" {{action addFoo obj}}> Add foo </a>

{{#if obj.foo}}
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="obj.foo"}}
{{/if}}
```

Then in my action `addFoo`, I do:

```
obj.set('foo', 1);
```

and that will make the input field appear.

I have two problems with this approach:

1. `1` is really an arbitrary value, it doesn't have any special meaning in my application.
2. If the user deletes `1` because they want to type `2`, the input field will disappear before they have the time to type `2`.

Is there a better approach to this kind of user interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a computed property to my model:

```
fooIsSet: function() { return this.get('foo') !== null }.property('foo')
```

So that in my `handlebars` template I could do this:

```
{{#if obj.fooIsSet}}
  do stuff
{{/if}}
```

This way I can deal with `null` only, and `''` will act as if the property is set and valid.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your question but check this out, if this is what you require:

property `foo` is an array of length 0 i.e.

```
foo: []
```

**Handlebars file**

```
<a href="#" {{action addTextField obj}} class="btn">Add Foo</a>
{{#each foo}}
  {{view Ember.Textfield}}
{{/each}}
```

adding textfield:

```
addTextField: function(){
  obj.get('foo').pushObject(1);
}
```

Therefore, number of textfields = length of array `foo` If you need to retain bindings of the textfield value, go with following approach:(Once again `obj.foo` is an empty array)

```
obj.textFieldView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  contentBinding: 'foo',
  itemViewClass: Ember.Textfield.extend({
    valueBinding: 'this.content'
  })
})

obj.addTextField = function(){
  obj.get('foo').pushObject("");
}
```

**Handlebars file**

```
<a href="#" {{action addTextField obj}} class="btn">Add Foo</a>
{{#collection obj.textFieldView}}
{{/collection}}
```

Whenever you click "Add Foo" a new textfield is added & whatever u enter in the textfield is bound to the "foo" array....Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, even though it's probably not what I was looking for (and that's my bad because I should've put more effort into asking the question.)
The reason why that doesn't work is that your are making `foo` an array, while it's supposed to be a single property like a person's `name`.

I ended up doing this: `foo: null, fooIsSet: function() { return foo !== null; }.property('foo')`

This way, in my `handlebars` template I check for `fooIsSet`, and when `foo` is `""` I'm gonna get `true`.

Comment: I used an array because I thought whenever we click add button it should add a textfield...anyways good to know you got the solution